# Unable to Install

Tags: windows, keyboard, iso

I have been trying to install Ubuntu on my PC for some time now. I tried wubi, but am unable to get it right. Then, I downloaded the ISO and tried to install it on an empty without partitioning, but the **keyboard acts wierd and goes on typing automatically** one particular letter that was typed while trying to enter IPv4 settings (2222222222 or ............, etc...) and also I get an **error about some fsyncing\sdk\resourses something like that**. Please help me.

**UPDATE:** I managed to install it but I get a blank screen after logging in. Just the wallpaper shows up! Help me.

Comment: Can you please provide error log

for bug reporting launch pad is the best choice